# Is the libcurl supported in the latest android versions

Tags: java, android, curl, libcurl

I m wondering if the `libcurl` is supported in the latest android version (4.0 +). Because I think I saw some where that it's supported in the new android versions but I m looking for a confirmation.

If yes, How I can call the `libcurl` functions in my `JNI` source code? and How to update the `Android.mk`in order to refer the so lib of the `libcurl`?

Comment: Hope [this](http://qiankanglai.me/misc/2014/08/31/android-libcurl/) step by step tutorial helps you

Comment: @HBizhi, So I have to support it my self by rebuilding the android source code?

Comment: As the writer said if you use the similar version, you could just copy & paste the results there. But otherwise yes, you should rebuild it. Maybe there exist other solutions which I don't have any idea about them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no. Libcurl does not exist in the external packages in the android source code. it should be supported in a custom android version.